# How to index USGS ARD Satellite Data into an Open Data Cube?

Tags: data, satellite, usgs, open-data-cube

I am trying to index a Landsat8-Satellite-Dataset from Massachusetts in the USA. I downloaded the dataset from USGS. Below my question you can find the datacube-metadata.yaml-File. It is surface reflectance data and Analysis Ready Data (ARD). When I am now trying to index the data with: `datacube -v dataset add PATH/datacube-metadata.yaml` there occurs the error: `ERROR No matching Product found for dataset`

I think that the problem lies in the Product Definition File. I have used the Product Definition File from Swiss Data Cube: https://github.com/GRIDgva/SwissDataCube/blob/master/ingestors/Landsat/ls8_c1_ard_scene.yaml

I also tried to write one by myself but there is always the same error. Has someone an idea how to solve the error?

**datacube-metadata.yaml-File:**

```
acquisition:

aos:
'2018-10-30 15:32:36'

groundstation: {code:
_20}

los:
'2018-10-30 15:33:00'

creation_dt: 2018-10-30 00:00:00

extent:

center_dt:
'2018-10-30 15:32:48'

coord:

ll: {lat:
41.543343249666286,
lon: 
-74.26101678236896}

lr: {lat:
41.22740733220001,
lon: 
-72.50449089590899}

ul: {lat:
42.84901849362111,
lon: 
-73.84246819961363}

ur: {lat:
42.52663821973187,
lon: 
-72.05488589831796}

from_dt:
'2018-10-30 15:32:36'

to_dt:
'2018-10-30 15:33:00'

format: {name:
GeoTiff}

grid_spatial:

projection:

geo_ref_points:

ll: {x:
1784415.0, 
y: 2264805.0}

lr: {x:
1934415.0, 
y: 2264805.0}

ul: {x:
1784415.0, 
y: 2414805.0}

ur: {x:
1934415.0, 
y: 2414805.0}

spatial_reference:
PROJCS["Albers",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS

84",6378140,298.2569999999957,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",29.5],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",45.5],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",23],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",-96],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]

id: 94675613-a468-45cd-850f-d6423beb4d61

image:

bands:

LINEAGEQA: {path:
LC08_CU_029006_20181030_20190613_C01_V01_LINEAGEQA.tif}

PIXELQA: {path:
LC08_CU_029006_20181030_20190613_C01_V01_PIXELQA.tif}

RADSATQA: {path:
LC08_CU_029006_20181030_20190613_C01_V01_RADSATQA.tif}

SRAEROSOLQA: {path:
LC08_CU_029006_20181030_20190613_C01_V01_SRAEROSOLQA.tif}

SRB1: {path:
LC08_CU_029006_20181030_20190613_C01_V01_SRB1.tif}

SRB2: {path:
LC08_CU_029006_20181030_20190613_C01_V01_SRB2.tif}

SRB3: {path:
LC08_CU_029006_20181030_20190613_C01_V01_SRB3.tif}

SRB4: {path:
LC08_CU_029006_20181030_20190613_C01_V01_SRB4.tif}

SRB5: {path:
LC08_CU_029006_20181030_20190613_C01_V01_SRB5.tif}

SRB6: {path:
LC08_CU_029006_20181030_20190613_C01_V01_SRB6.tif}

SRB7: {path:
LC08_CU_029006_20181030_20190613_C01_V01_SRB7.tif}

satellite_ref_point_end: {x:
29, 
y: 6}

satellite_ref_point_start: {x:
29, 
y: 6}

instrument: {name:
OLI/TIRS}

lineage:

source_datasets: {}

platform: {code:
LANDSAT_8}

processing_level:
T1

product_type:
LaSRC
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution:
The instrumentname and the bandnames aren't **exact** the same in the datacube-metadata.yaml-File and in the product definition. If I change these names in the product definition the data is successfully indexed.